# React Native Animate not updating on initial state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have a button component that uses an image wrapped in an Animated.View component. When pressed the external state (stored in React Context) is updated, the current offset of the button is added to an array which represents the buttons that have been clicked.

```
const ToggleButton = memo(
  ({offset, icon}: ToggleButtonProps) => {
    const {
      onValueToggle,
      track,
    } = useViewContext();

    const currentValue = track.includes(offset) ? 1 : 0;
    const value = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    useEffect(() => {
      Animated.timing(value, {
        toValue: currentValue,
        duration: 150,
        easing,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }, [currentValue]);

    const onPress = useCallback(() => {
      onValueToggle(offset);
    }, []);

    const buttonStyles = {
      opacity: value.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0.4, 1],
      }),
      transform: [
        {
          scale: value.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0.8, 1],
          }),
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={onPress}>
        <Animated.View style={buttonStyles}>
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={icon}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  },
);
```

The values all update correctly, if the first button is clicked the **track** array becomes [0], and when clicked again the **track** value is [] so the **currentValue** value will toggle between 0 and 1. This triggers the **useEffect** that should update the Animated value.

Whats happening though is on the first click nothing happens, the second click on the same button will trigger two animations, the initial opacity/transform change and then the revert to initial state. This process repeats if I keep clicking the same button.

If I click on another button after clicking the first button then both animations are started together.

I think I'm missing something with how the states are saved in Hooks but I can't figure out where.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

It was the **TouchableWithoutFeedback** that was causing the issue, it worked as expected when replaced it with another **Touchable** or a **Pressable**.